# JCL IF statement on multiple lines

Tags: jcl

I'm getting JCL error when executing this job.

```
// IF &O = O AND                              
//       (&GEG = SD.SD.SYNC.DB2.LBER OR       
//        &GEG = SD.LA.SYNC.DB2.LBER OR       
//        &GEG = SD.TW.SYNC.DB2.LBER)         
//STEP015 EXEC COZ,PNAME=IN0603ZC
```

Expected continuation not found. When I type '+' after every line for the IF, the total length is greater than 80 which also gives problems. Please help me :)

Comment: You know that you can only test for numerics? O is not numeric. If those long things are data set names, you can't do that. If they're not data set names, what are they? What are you actually trying to do? I think you have not attempted to understand a JCL IF statement, and think that you can just jam in anything you like. You can't.

Comment: I'm assuming you've just not showed the ENDIF.

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean about the +. Can you show that, and the message you get when 80 gives you a problem?

Comment: @Bill: Indeed, the ENDIF isn't shown

Comment: &O is the environment we are testing in. O stands for development (in Dutch it is "Ontwikkeling"). The names after the &GEG are names of MQ's. We are using a tool called Dialog Manager which determines in which environment you are testing (development, acceptation, production). I've written a new program called IN0603ZC. It's only yet in development stage. With this JCL I'm trying to say: "If we're in development AND one of 3 MQ names in the IF statement is chosen THEN execute my new program IN0603ZC.

Comment: Well, you'll have to arrange it differently. The IF in JCL is not a general-purpose "if" like you think it is. Have a look at the JCL Reference. Read about the IF. If still unsure of a way to proceed, update your question with the information in the comment, and what it is that is unclear about your understanding of the JCL IF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to create another solution. Like Bill Woodger said before: You can test only on numerics in a JCL. Thankx all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the z/OS MVS JCL syntax reference](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieab600/iea3b6_Syntax99.htm):

> ```
> //[name] IF  [(]relational-expression[)] THEN   [comments]
>     .
>     .    action when relational-expression is true
>     .
> //[name] ELSE   [comments]
>     .
>     .    action when relational-expression is false
>     .
> //[name] ENDIF   [comments]
> ```
>
> The IF statement consists of the characters // in columns 1 and 2 and
>   the five fields: name, operation (IF), the relational-expression, the
>   characters THEN, and comments. The relational-expression can be
>   enclosed in parentheses.
>
> The ELSE statement consists of the characters // in columns 1 and 2
>   and the three fields: name, operation (ELSE), and comments.
>
> The ENDIF statement consists of the characters // in columns 1 and 2
>   and the three fields: name, operation (ENDIF), and comments.

Your JCL is missing `THEN`

Comment: @JorenWillems you have a reference for that (re-commenting after typoing the username)

Comment: Okay I'll try again with the THEN statement included.